# Using cURL to return API XML response

Tags: php, xml, curl

Forgive me if this is simple. My research has brought me to a halt at the moment. I am trying to use cURL to get the response of an API in XML.

This is the URL of the API: https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active/region/land

By default it returns in JSON. Which I know, I should just use the JSON response but, there is a reason I need it in XML as it will seamlessly integrate into my current code until I can rewrite it for JSON.

This is the documentation for the API. Under the API Reference tab is states I just need to change the request header to application/cap+xml. But I am not getting anything back. Just a blank white page.

https://alerts-v2.weather.gov/documentation

Here is my current code I am using to call the API but I get no response or anything. What am I missing?

```
    <?php

     $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
     $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/cap+xml;charset=utf-8';
     $headers[] = 'Accept: application/cap+xml';

     $userAgent = 'php';

     $url = 'https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active/region/land';

     $cURL = curl_init();

     curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
     curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
     curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);

     $result = curl_exec($cURL);

     curl_close($cURL);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried your code and it works fine with atom:

```
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/atom+xml';
```

"application/cap+xml" is not available for the URLs, like you mentioned in a question though.

Per the doc https://alerts-v2.weather.gov/documentation the formats are following:

```
/alerts/active/region/{region} => JSON-LD (default), ATOM 
/alerts/{alertId}   => JSON-LD (default), CAP
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it with atom+xml and I am getting nothing back still Just a blank white page. This was just updated in May so it's not outdate as it is their new API just released. Here is an example with the XML response from their page. https://alerts-v2.weather.gov/products/active?region_type=land

Comment: Ah I was missing the echo statement. I am getting a response now but when I request it in cap+xml it returns it in JSON.

Comment: Yes I understand but, ATOM is something they are trying to get away from. This is a new API has of May 2017 so the cap+xml is maintained. Here is an example. Also if you click on XML from there it will show you a preview of the response using cap+xml so it is very much maintained. https://alerts-v2.weather.gov/products/active?region_type=land

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151802/discussion-between-texan78-and-axalix).

Comment: At the end of the day issue was due to 2 factions. I was missing the echo statement. Also what I wanted to do wasn't available in CAP. So need to just bite the bullet and switch to JSON sooner than later.